# Can I protect with a .htaccess file some routes with sinatra?

Tags: ruby, .htaccess, sinatra

I wrote a small app with Sinatra and have some admin routes (/admin/new, admin/edit/2, ...) and want to protect them with a .htaccess prompt. Can somebody tell me how I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/file/.htpasswd

<Files "protected.html">
Require valid-user
</Files>
```

If you want to use Sinatra for Authentication, check out [this faq](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#auth).